# Modifying new operator using my API

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator, delete-operator

I want to modify the `new` and the `delete` operator in the toolchain with the custom API of the processor.
There are a few memory allocation issues so the vendor says I have to modify them like this.
In tool chain I go to the header file named "new"
and checked these

```
void* operator new(std::size_t) throw (std::bad_alloc);
void* operator new[](std::size_t) throw (std::bad_alloc);
void operator delete(void*) throw();
void operator delete[](void*) throw();
```

I want to do something like using

```
using namespace std;  
if( size == 0 )  
    size = 1;  
while( true ){  
    void* pMem = my_api_malloc(size);  
    if( pMem )      
        return pMem;  
}
```

Is it the right approach?
Can I make such change where `my_api_malloc` is the one which I am supposed to use.
This is because the processor primarily uses C and the C++ operators are not recognized.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Please do _not_ tag questions with both the [tag:c++] tag and the [tag:c] tag.  While there are occasionally circumstances in which it is correct to use both, this is not one of them — there is no `new` operator in C so there is no way to modify it either.

Comment: Sorry.I will keep it in mind the next time. I tagged C as my processor supported C and not c++.

Comment: If you have any C++ code in the program, you will need the C++ support library, and that will include the `new` and `delete` operators.  Your code fragment isn't inside a function; it is presumably a `new` operator of some sort.  You haven't shown your proposed replacement `delete` operators.  It might be a reasonable basis — it isn't clear what's going to happen if `my_api_malloc()` continually returns a null pointer.  The standard has some requirements on what a `new` operator is supposed to do; you'll need to read up and handle those.

Comment: Thank Mr.Jonathan. I wanted to add the fragment inside the                 new(std::size_t) throw (){
  using namespace std;  
  if( size == 0 )  
    size = 1;  
    while( true ){  
    void* pMem = my_api_malloc (size);  
    if( pMem )      
      return pMem;

Comment: I have replaced my code fragment in this  `inline void* operator new(std::size_t, void* __p) throw() { my fragment } ` @JonathanLeffler

Comment: I don't remember the rules for writing your own `new` and `delete`. It is not something that novice programmers normally do. Roughly, if you need to ask about how to do it, you probably shouldn't be trying. I would not try. Since I don't remember, I would have to research to answer your question. I don't feel like doing the research tonight, so you'll have to find someone else willing to help. There is information in one of the Effective C++ books; I think it is the first edition rather than the latest, though. Your motivation for attempting it isn't clear; the reasons given aren't compelling.

Comment: What do you mean by _processor_? Do you mean the preprocessor? Maybe the CPU? How about the compiler?

Comment: by processor I mean my hardware on which I must flash the code. the vendor has given the toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not able to write this in comment due to the lack of reputation. I think that you should not do malloc in a while loop. If there is no more memory that OS can allocate for the process, no matter how you do the malloc, it's in vain. Also please be aware not to `free` what is created by `new` in C++, and not to `delete` what is created by `malloc`.

Memory allocation in C

```
int *a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
if(!a)
  return 1;
```

and in C++

```
try{
  int *a= new int[n];
}
catch (std::bad_alloc &e){
  // ...
}
```